# Not able to skip the 1st iteration in foreach-object using continue statement.Please suggest

Tags: powershell

Hi i have powershell where i am using a foreach-object and would like to skip the first iteration always. And i am using continue statement as well. But the current behaviour of continue is like break. Please suggest if something i am doing wrong here.

Below is the sample code.

```
$xmlfile = 'D:\testdirecotry\sample.xml'
[xml]$xmlcontent = (Get-Content $xmlfile)
$folderprefix = 'plm_z'
$regex = '<!--__AMAZONSITE id="(.+?)" instance="(.+?)"__-->'
$i=0

(Get-Content $xmlfile) | select-string -Pattern $regex | ForEach-Object {

    write-host "Test Iterartion"

    if($i -eq 0)
    {
        write-host "entering if loop"
        write-host $i
        $i++
        write-host $i
        continue
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "entering else loop"
        write-host $_   
        $pscustomobject=@(
            # write-host $_
            $id = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value        
            $instance = $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value      

            write-host "Do Something"

        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier way to skip the first object would potentially be to use `Select-Object` in the pipeline:

```
Get-Content $xmlfile |
  Select-string -Pattern $regex |
  Select-Object -Skip 1 |
  ForEach-Object {
    ...
```